# Graph of negative exponential function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Is it possible to graph a function

$Y = (-2)^x$ where $x \geq 1$

It is written in my text that exponential functions are only defined for positive bases, but why not negative bases having restriction on domain ($x$) of function  which would not give minus sign under square root. I am new to this stuff so please help me even if it looks silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all due respect, your textbook is incorrect. Exponential functions are very well defined regardless of te sign of the base. They just may or may not have the range in the real numbers.

Go to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) and plug in your function with a negative base. There you will find an example of how to plot the graph of this function. (The real and imaginary components are plotted against the input)

Alternatively, you may plot a 3D curve where the axes would be: x: input, y: real part and z: imaginary part.

Hope this helps.